# div is not taking up all its physical space

Tags: html, css

Visually, the `div` element displays as intended. However, the actual div (wrapped in an `a` link) spans across the whole page. Here's an illustration of what I mean:

[image: descriptive illustration]

The button is an image file, if that helps.

HTML:

```
<a href="../SpeedUp.zip">
    <div class=download>
        <img class=download src="../img/download.png"></img>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
div.download {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(#8ab081, #77ab59);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}

div.download:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#8db87c, #88aa8a);
}

img.download {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Thanks, SO!

Comment: it's because you have fixed the width of the div. make it 100% (it will take same width as it's parent div)

Comment: Thanks @AsitVachhani, but I am going to go with Math Nerd Productions' answer. Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: I would suggest don't wrap the `div` inside a `a` element. bcz in theory `inline` element cannot contain any `block` elements. since `div` is block element so this is the reason its occupying the full 100% width.

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying @KheemaPandey. I'll remember that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divs are block elements, which means that they can't occupy the same line with any other elements.

While you changed the width of the element to be only 200px, your browser will automatically place margin directly to the right of the div to fill the rest of the space of that line.

If you want to allow divs to wrap with other elements, you can set the display to inline-block:

```
div.download
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```